# Is it normal to fetch the entire DB with the entity framework?

Tags: performance, entity-framework

In the application we are developping, we have the following code

```
        EntityContext entity = TransactionManager.GetEntityContext();
        int idType = entity.InfoSectnGess.Where(e => e.NoSeqInfoSecGes == noSeqInfoSecGes).Single().NoSeqTypeInfo;
        return entity.ListValues.Where(e => e.NoSeqTypeInfo == idType && e.NoSeqChoixValeur == noSeq).Single().DescChoixValeur;
```

*EntityContext* is based on **System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext**

When I run the debugger, put a break point at the first line and look at what **entity** contains, I see that it contains all the "*tables*" (entity fields?) in the DB, but they are all empty (null).

If I go to the next step, then my "*tables*" are filled with... well... the whole DB.

Of course, my concern here is performances.

Is that solution viable or will it become too slow with time?

I asked a the *guy behind this idea* and he told me there would be no such troubles. Yet, when I see that *entity.InfoSectnGess* contains 380 elements (temporary data for dev) and that it will contains a few thousands, if not millions of records quickly, it makes me wonder... Where's and what's the magic?

Comment: EF doesn't work that way. Post the code of the GetEntityContext() method.

Comment: If your ObjectContext has Lazy Loading enabled, it will bring the data as soon as you shift+F9 when debugging in Visual Studio. It does not happen when running the application normally.

Comment: Then again, if you need 1 record from the DB use `FirstOrDefault` or `First` if you're sure it's always going to be there, instead of `Where()` and after that `.Single()`.